# I wrote a program to handle unit conversions in Prolog, but I always get stack-overflows: Do you know why?

Tags: prolog, stack-overflow, gnu-prolog

The problem continues regardless of refactoring, but it changes, if I switch line 6 and 7 I get different results? How could that even be possible?

If relevent this is gnuprolog on a MacOS Monterey (version 12.6.2) device.

Here is the relevent code:

```
conversion(meters, 82/25, feet).
conversion(feet,   12/1,  in  ).
conversion(hr,     60/1,  min ).
conversion(min,    60/1,  sec ).

conversion(Unit1, X/Y, Unit2)     :- conversion(Unit2, Y/X, Unit1), !.
conversion(Unit1, Num/Den, Unit3) :- conversion(Unit1, X/Y, Unit2), conversion(Unit2, A/B, Unit3), Num is X * A, Den is Y*B.
```

Whever I enter a question that requires more then a single *inversion* (as in the second to last rule) I get an error. So,

```
conversion(meters,X,in).  
conversion(hr,X,sec).
conversion(in, X, meters).
```

Cause,

```
Fatal Error: local stack overflow (size: 16384 Kb, reached: 16384 Kb, environment variable used: LOCALSZ)
```

But

```
conversion(min,X,hr).
conversion(feet,X,meters).
```

Produce the expected results. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a predicate name different to `conversion` for the rules, to prevent the infinite recursion. Use e.g. `trace` to see it, by [stepping through the code](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I need it to do several layers deep of recursion, lots of what I want isn't derivable in just a single step. Does that make sense?

Comment: Getting from `meters` to `in` (i.e. inches) is a *path* - can search the Internet using keywords e.g. "prolog" and "path" to see lots of example code. Use a list variable to keep track of what's been visited already, to prevent an infinite loop from repeatedly visiting e.g. "feet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following appears to work, thanks @brebs!

```
conversion(meters, 82/25,feet   ).
conversion(feet,   12/1, inches ).
conversion(hours,  60/1, minutes).
conversion(minutes,60/1, seconds).

walk(Unit1, X/Y, Unit3, Vs) :-
     conversion(Unit1, X/Y, Unit3);
     conversion(Unit3, Y/X, Unit1);
     \+ member(Unit2, Vs),
     walk(Unit1, A/B,  Unit2, [Unit2|Vs]),
     walk(Unit2, C/D , Unit3, [Unit2|Vs]),
     N is A * C, M is B * D,
     gcd(N,M,Z),
     X is N // Z,
     Y is M // Z.

ratio(Unit1, X/Y, Unit2) :- walk(Unit1, X/Y, Unit2, []).

gcd(X, 0, X):- !.
gcd(0, X, X):- !.
gcd(X, Y, D):- X =< Y, !, Z is Y - X, gcd(X, Z, D).
gcd(X, Y, D):- gcd(Y, X, D).
```

Comment: In your `\+ member(Unit2, Vs),`, `Unit2` is uninstantiated at that point. It needs to be instantiated. Then, within `walk` you won't need to be calling `walk` *twice*.

Comment: That `gcd` definition looks wrong, due to testing for equality in the *head*, e.g. `X, 0, X`. The order must be: test for 0, cut, test for equality.

Comment: do you want, like,
`(conversion(Unit1, A/B, Unit2) ; conversion(Unit2, B/A, Unit1)), \+ member(Unit2, Vs), walk(Unit2, C/D, Unit3, [Unit2|Vs]),...`?

This is my first prolog program, so I admit I find some of your suggestions a little vexing, why is it bad to call walk twice?